# ASP-PAGE not redirecting. ASP NET CORE MVC 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, identity

I'm using the .NET IDENTITY and I'm having an issue when trying to redirect to a razor page in my identity area.

This is the code sample that should do the redirect thing,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1Ged.png)
btw: this is the code generated by the visual studio itself
`<a class="nav-link text-dark" id="login" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>`

which should redirect me to the Login page, but it doesn't and all that I get is this weird path on the url

```
https://localhost:44316/?area=Identity&page=%2FAccount%2FLogin
```

Comment: Is your  account contoller in identity area?if not you don't want to specify area

Comment: Usually account controller never ever should be in area .single log in everywhere.like Google for instance

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had to create another application using the Identity configuired by the visual studio (Individual accounts authentication) and look at its startup.cs and finally realize you gotta add this to your startup file in ConfigureServices()

```
services.AddRazorPages();
```

And this to  Configure();

```
     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
```

after that redirecting to razor pages should be ok